# C++ Decorator added to std::vector

Tags: c++, design-patterns, decorator, stdvector

I have a base class for a record, and want to add additional fields and comparison functions using decorators, and be able to chain the decorators (records can have an email, or a date of birth, or both, or none). I'm also going to have a lot of such decorators; one for each addtional field, and its comparison function. Once this is done, I'm going to add the objects to a vector, using a base class pointer.

Here's a precis of the code:

```
class BaseRecord
{
public:
    virtual bool Compare();     // defined elsewhere

protected:
    std::string m_strName;
    std::string m_strAddress:
};

class BaseDecorator : public BaseRecord
{
public:
    BaseDecorator(BaseRecord *pBase) : m_pBase(pBase){}

    bool Compare()
    {
        return m_pBase->Compare();
    }

private:
    BaseRecord *m_pBase;
};

class EmailDecorator : public BaseDecorator
{
public:
    EmailDecorator(BaseRecord *pBase) : EmailDecorator(pBase){}

    bool Compare()
    {
        if (!CompareEmail())        // defined elsewhere
        {
            return false;
        }

        BaseDecorator::Compare();
    }

private:
    std::string m_strEmail
};

class DOBDecorator : public BaseDecorator
{
public:
    DOBDecorator(BaseRecord *pBase) : DOBDecorator(pBase){}

    bool Compare()
    {
        if (!CompareDOB())      // defined elsewhere
        {
            return false;
        }

        BaseDecorator::Compare();
    }

private:
    std::string m_strDOB;
};
```

Those are the classes. What I'd now like to do is add them to a vector:

```
vector<BaseRecord *> m_vecRecords;

BaseRecord pRecord = new BaseRecord();

// wrong - copies pointer only to vector
m_vecRecords.push_back(pRecord);

// OK - default copy constructor for BaseRecord used
m_vecRecords.push_back(new BaseRecord(*pRecord));

// now chain the decorators

// pRecord is a BaseRecord
BaseRecord pRecord = new EmailDecorator(pRecord);

//wrong - copies pointer only to vector
m_vecRecords.push_back(pRecord);

// ??? needs copy constructor
m_vecRecords.push_back(new EmailDecorator(*pRecord));

// pRecord is an EmailDecorator
BaseRecord pRecord = new DOBDecorator(pRecord);

// wrong - copies pointer only to vector
m_vecRecords.push_back(pRecord);

// ??? needs copy constructor
m_vecRecords.push_back(new DOBDecorator(*pRecord));
```

Now attempt to write the copy constructors:

```
// should p be an EmailDecorator *, or a BaseDecorator * ?
EmailDecorator::EmailDecorator(const EmailDecorator *p)
{
    // this will leak - no delete in the destructor
    // I have not supplied a destructor
    m_pBase = new BaseDectorator(p);
    m_strEmail = p->m_strEmail;
}

// should p be a DOBDecorator *, or  BaseDecorator * ?
// in the above example, when the copy constructor is needed, it is an EmailDecorator *

DOBDecorator::DOBDecorator(const DOBDecorator *p)
{
    // this will leak - no delete in the destructor
    // I have not supplied a destructor
    m_pBase = new BaseDectorator(p);
    m_strDOB = p->m_strDOB;
}
```

So how do I write the copy constructors to do a deep copy, and be able to free up the allocated memory? I feel like I'm missing something and that there's a way to do this without having to supply copy constructors?

Comment: In short - for deep-copying a polymorphic object held through a pointer/reference to base class, you need not only copy constructors, but also a virtual `clone()`-like function.

Comment: a slightly different take on the decorator pattern it to have the base object keep a list of decorators, somewhat more manual work, but works better with c++/STL

Comment: Angew - thanks, the clone idiom is an excellent idea.

Comment: sp2danny - yes, you're right. I've rewritten my decorator to have a base class inheriting from the base record, then all of my concrete decorators inherit from the base decorator.

Comment: What does the `Compare` function compare to?

Answer (score 2):

You are not off by much, in terms of Decorator; unfortunately you are off by a long shot in terms of C++.

In terms of `Decorator`, the main issue you have is that your *interface* should not hold any value. Otherwise, as is the case here, a `BaseDecorator` object has *at least* two `name` fields:

- one from its base class
- one from its member

and you forgot to initialize the one from the base class.

In terms of C++, unfortunately this get complicated because you have not considered *ownership*. In languages featuring a garbage collector you can cut corners but in C++ this does not work.

So let us rectify this, should we ?

---

First of all, we need a clean interface:

```
class IRecord {
public:
    virtual bool lessThan(IRecord const& other) const = 0;
};
```

I'll let you figure out how to actually compare two records; it might not be easy using a decorator approach because there is no guarantee that just because `this` is an `EmailDecorator`, other also has an `EmailDecorator` *somewhere* in its chain.

Then, we can build a decorator approach, and we are going to do so using a strong ownership claim:

```
class RecordDecorator: public IRecord {
protected:
    RecordDecorator(std::unique_ptr<IRecord> r): _decorated(std::move(r)) {}

private:
    std::unique_ptr<IRecord> _decorated;
};
```

We can build our first stone too:

```
class BaseRecord final: public IRecord {
public:
    BaseRecord(std::string name, std::string address):
        _name(std::move(name)), _address(std::move(address)) {}

    virtual bool lessThan(IRecord const& record) const override;

private:
    std::string _name;
    std::string _address;
}; // class BaseRecord
```

And then, we can finally try and create a *value-class* (that is, a class that can be manipulated by value) from this:

```
class Record {
public:
    Record(std::string name, std::string address):
        _data(std::make_unique<BaseRecord>(std::move(name), std::move(address)) {}

    bool lessThan(Record const& other) const {
        return _data->lessThan(other._data);
    }

    template <typename D, typename... Args>
    void decorate(Args&&... args) {
        _data = std::make_unique<D>(std::move(_data), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<IRecord> _data;
}; // class Record
```

This design is sound:

- it does not leak memory,
- it does not keep several divergent copies of data-members,
- and it is easy to manipulate (for a client)

However, as it stands, `Record` will not have a copy constructor (nor a copy assignment operator), because `std::unique_ptr` misses those.

If you wish to add them, you need add a `virtual std::unique_ptr<IRecord> clone() const = 0` (*) to `IRecord` which will be in charge of the in-depth copy. That is where our `RecordDecorator` shines:

```
class RecordDecorator: public IRecord {
protected:
    RecordDecorator(std::unique_ptr<IRecord> r): _decorated(std::move(r)) {}

    RecordDecorator(RecordDecorator const& other):
        _decorated(other._decorated->clone()) {}

    RecordDecorator& operator=(RecordDecorator const& other) {
        if (this == &other) { return *this; }
        _decorated = other._decorated.clone();
        return *this;
    }

    // These two got disabled when we wrote our own copy constructor
    // and copy assignment operator, so let's re-enable them.
    RecordDecorator(RecordDecorator&&) = default;
    RecordDecorator& operator=(RecordDecorator&&) = default;

private:
    std::unique_ptr<IRecord> _decorated;
};
```

Now, any class inheriting from `RecordDecorator` automatically gets a copy-constructor and copy-assignment-operator providing it does not contain non-copiable members of its own.

And we can also improve `Record` with the requested copying:

```
Record::Record(Record const& other):
    _data(other._data.clone())
{}

Record& Record::operator=(Record const& other) {
    if (this == &other) { return *this; }
    _data = other._data.clone();
    return *this;
}

// These two got disabled when we wrote our own copy constructor
// and copy assignment operator, so let's re-enable them.
Record::Record(Record&&) = default;
Record& Record::operator=(Record&&) = default;
```

And icing on the cake, how to use all that:

```
class EmailDecorator final: public RecordDecorator {
public:
    EmailDecorator(std::unique_ptr<IRecord> base, std::string email):
        RecordDecorator(std::move(base)), _email(email) {}

    virtual std::unique_ptr<IRecord> clone() const override {
        return std::make_unique<EmailDecorator>(*this);
    }

    virtual bool lessThan(IRecord const&) const override; // up to you ;)

private:
    std::string _email;
}; // class EmailDecorator

int main() {
    Record record{"John, Doe", "12345 Mimosa Road, 3245 Washington DC"};
    record.decorate<EmailDecorator>("john.doe@aol.com");

    std::vector<Record> vec;
    vec.push_back(record); // make a copy
    vec.back().decorate<EmailDecorator>("doe.john@msn.com"); // another e-mail!
}
```

But... adding fields via decoration will make any logic on those fields pretty awkward... and you'll know the pain soon: as soon as you try to implement `lessThan` actually.